# Optimize the background image in phonegap

Tags: image, cordova, optimization, background

How can i optimize the background image for any screen size in a phonegap application?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVG as image and in CSS use this:

```
body{
    background-image: url('...');
    background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

Assuming your image layout to be always same.